# PHP - file_get_contents System Error?

Tags: php, html, parsing

I'm trying to parse the html from a url. I do this:

```
$html = file_get_contents($someURL);
echo $html;
```

But when I run that script, the page shows this:

```
UISCGI (software8a-web; software8a-link):
This site is best viewed with Netscape 4.6 or 4.7 or Internet Explorer 5 and greater.
At this time Netscape 6 is not supported for Link usage.
```

I also tried CURLing the url, while faking IE7 as the User Agent.

**What's going wrong here? I couldn't find this error anywhere with Google. How do I get past this system error?**

Comment: Ask site owner for permission to get the data legally?

Comment: I've done this. No response yet. It seems like there should be an easy way to fix the system error, though.

Comment: Reads like that (university?) server is running pretty outdated software. Try faking the Netscape4 user-agent instead of IE7, also add a Referer: header.

Comment: What's the URL? Is it using client-side browser detection, like JS or Flash? There's always a way, as long as it's legit, just have a closer look at what's going on behind the scenes using Firebug or something. Or post the URL and let us have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found such an adress, faking of the user-agent works fine. Maybe the setting of the header is wrong in your case.

simple example:

```
<?php
   //fake IE6
  ini_set('user_agent', "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0)\r\n");
   //request
  echo file_get_contents('http://www.bu.edu/link/');
?>
```

(without the ini_set() I get the same output like you)

Note: From PHP5 on file_get_contents() also allows setting of headers via the optional context-parameter-